# Python: нужно ли закрывать файл, открытый таким образом?

Tags: python, файлы

Открытие и закрытие файла записывается так:

```
log = open(logFile,"a")
log.write(message)
log.close()
```

Или так: файл закрывается автоматически:

```
with open(logFile, "a") as log: log.write(message)
```

Но недавно я наткнулся на

```
open(logFile,"a").write(message)
```

Это прекрасная лаконичная запись. Она мне очень нравится. Но нужно ли закрывать файл в таком случае? и как это сделать?

Пытался найти информацию на эту тему но повсюду только копипаста первых двух способов.

Comment: Где вы на такое наткнулись, можете дать ссылку? На первый взгляд выглядит анти-паттерном. Так делать плохо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл открытый таким образом запишется на диск и закроется не в предсказуемое время. Если таких открытий сделать много, то возможны глюки и коллизии.

После выхода из функции что его вызвала его должен сожрать Гарбедж Коллектор. В какой момент он это сделает не известно. При удалении объекта через GC файл закрывается.

Comment: ну а закрыть его в таком случае нельзя?

Comment: @cordonballas нельзя, нет возможности получить хэндл, хотя может есть какие-то косвенные способы, откуда-то его добыть

Comment: GC закроет. Добавил в ответ.